# Capybara::ElementNotFound when element is clearly on page

Tags: testing, capybara

I am currently trying to fix a Capybara error that came out of no where. It is causing all of my test to fail. These test use to work and I am not sure what has changed as the error doesn't make much sense

The Error

```
Unable to find visible field "Username" that is not disabled (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

The HTML I get from puts on page.body and save_and_open_page

```
<div class="login-field">
   <span><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i></span>
   <span><input autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="user[username]" id="user_username"></span>
</div>
<div class="login-field">
   <password-entry the-id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password" show-lock="true"></password-entry>
 </div>
```

The test itself

```
fill_in "Username", with: "username"
fill_in 'Password', with: "password"
click_button "Login"
```

I have tried to do finds and also look ups by id. I think the error must be deeper then it not finding the element because it clearly is rendering the element

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: selenium-webdriver (3.13.0) and firefox

Comment: Have you used `save_and_open_screenshot` to verify what you expect to be visible actually is?

Comment: Yup that is where I got super confused and started to think it is a deeper issue

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using?  The only thing that's really changed in Capybara recently that could possible affect this is around disabled fieldsets -- do these inputs happen to be inside a fieldset element?  Also are the `fill_in` calls inside any sort of scoping (`within`, etc)

Comment: capybara (3.3.1) It was upgraded but I also rollbacked and still got the same error. The fill_in isn't inside any scope. I did try it in a sleep and wait_to_load to make sure the page had enough time to load. The same error showed up

Comment: Assuming you haven't changed the builtin `:fillable_field` selector (`Capybara.add_selector` or `Capybara.modify_selector`) then the info presented doesn't make any sense - If the HTML in your question is actually the visible elements on the page while the test is running (not replaced by some JS widget) then they should be found (Just add a long sleep before filling in and inspect the page using the developer console in the browser to confirm).

Comment: Oh -- one other thing it could be is if the fields are descendants of a wrapping element with a `hidden` attribute.  Some versions of geckodriver/FF incorrectly return that the descendants are non-visible even if the `display` property is modified thereby overriding the `hidden` attribute. I thought that was fixed in recent geckodriver/FF though.

Comment: I just tried save_and_open_screenshot and compared to save_and_open_page. Something weird is happening where the screenshot is gray but the open_page does render semi correct html. The form is there but some other elements are missing

Comment: The screenshot is the current state of the browser - so if that's showing the controls grayed out (not clear what you mean by "is gray") then that's your problem - `save_and_open_page` can be useful for debugging some things but doesn't accurately show the full current state of the page.  Just pausing/sleeping the test and then interacting with the browser you're testing with is usually the best way to actually debug the issue.

Comment: Was able to figure it out. Nothing was actually wrong with the test. There was a js file that had es6 in it but was just .js. This cause angular to not load causing none of the css to load which caused all of the html on the page to display:none

Comment: that should have been pretty obvious by just looking at the browser while the test was running.

Comment: the browser ignored the fact that it was es6 inside js while the test didn't......seems to be a very strange edge case

Comment: That explanation isn't possible if you were looking at the browser instance the test was running in (hence "while the test was running") -- Yes it's possible if you mean you looked at the browser in dev mode and assumed that was the same as test mode.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
find('css', visible: false).set("your text")
```